# Opencart import/export tool uploads XLS file, stops without error

Tags: pear, opencart, phpexcel, import-from-excel

I'm using the Opencart import/export tool (the one written by Mr. Neuhoff) to update our product database. I have not had any issues with it until just now... when I try to upload more than 12,000 products. After the XLS file is uploaded, the script just stops. No error. Nothing.

All error reporting is on. The tool is using PHP Pear (mini) library, and PHPExcel to parse through the data. My php.ini file is set to allow for up to eight gigs of RAM, and pretty much maxed out in every category. I'm at a total loss as to why this would be happening.

I'm totally open to ideas at this point. Anything I can try, would be very helpful.

Comment: Why not asking the extension developer?

Answer (score 0):

It was post_max_size error. Thanks to J.Neuhoff for bringing light to this, via the OC forum post [here](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=119&t=81305&start=60#p371728).